# str() error when running AWS Lambda (converting uuid to string) w/ Dynamo DB

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-lambda, boto3

I have tried converting a uuid to a string in the code below and I always get an error. Regardless of whether or not I declare str() separately from uuid.uuid4()
See Code Below:

```
    from __future__ import print_function
    from decimal import *
    import boto3
    import json
    from locale import str
    import uuid

    def my_handler(event, context):
        description = event['description'] 
        spot_id = uuid.uuid4() #Unique identifier for spot 
        dynamodb = boto3.client('dynamodb')
        tablesinfo = "sinfo"
        dynamodb.put_item(
        TableName = tablesinfo, Item = {
          'spot_id':{'S' : str(spot_id)},
          'description': {'S' : description
          }
        )
        return {'spot_id' : spot_id}
```

These are the errors I receive:

```
{
  "stackTrace": [
    [
      "/var/task/Create_Spot_Test.py",
      15,
      "my_handler",
      "'spot_id':{'S' : str(spot_id)},"
    ],
    [
      "/usr/lib64/python2.7/locale.py",
      303,
      "str",
      "return format(\"%.12g\", val)"
    ],
    [
      "/usr/lib64/python2.7/locale.py",
      196,
      "format",
      "return _format(percent, value, grouping, monetary, *additional)"
    ],
    [
      "/usr/lib64/python2.7/locale.py",
      202,
      "_format",
      "formatted = percent % value"
    ]
  ],
  "errorType": "TypeError",
  "errorMessage": "float argument required, not UUID"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`from locale import str` is not needed (was imported for a previous error)

Also you must first declare `uuid = uuid.uuid4()` as a variable and then declare another variable converting it to string `spot_id = str(uuid)` rather than running `str()` inline.